# How to get real root url in PHP (without framework)

Tags: php

I have 3 app in one public_html folder:

- /public_html/myapp_1
- /public_html/subfolder/myapp_2
- /public_html/subfolder3/small/myapp_3

when I run myapp_1 as sample.dev
=> So I got root url: sample.dev

when I run myapp_2 as sample.dev/subfolder
=> So I also got root url: sample.dev

when I run myapp_3 as sample.dev/subfolder3/small
=> I also got root url: sample.dev

But, I want to get:

- url of myapp_2 as "sample.dev/subfolder"
- url of myapp_3 as "sample.dev/subfolder/small".

This active will auto get with real container folder (not fixed)

Because I have a common function as:

function getFullAssetUrl('style.css');

This function will return:

- With myapp_1 => sample.dev/style.css
- With myapp_2 => sample.dev/subfolder/style.css
- With myapp_3 => sample.dev/subfolder3/small/style.css

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: show some code that you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this two PHP inbuild function useful.

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
```

OR use PHP getcwd();

```
<?php

// current directory
echo getcwd() . "\n";

chdir('cvs');

// current directory
echo getcwd() . "\n";

?>
```

Comment: I tried with document root, and its work for me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try it with `getcwd()`. Just pass your file to the function and it outputs the path to the file.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php

Answer (score 0):

Use base_url

```
<?php
   DEFINE('BASE_URL', HTTP_TYPE . "://" . HTTP_ROOT . substr(__DIR__, strlen($_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ])) . '/');
```

?>

Or, for current directory ,you can use getcwd()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php

Comment: Your code same as some framework, its worked, thanks for your help.